# Panda returns 50x1 matrix instead of 50x7? (read_csv gone wrong)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm quite new to Python. I'm trying to load a .csv file with Panda but it returns a 50x1 matrix instead of expected 50x7. I'm a bit uncertain whether it is becaue my data contains numbers with "," (although I thought the quotechar attribute would solve that problem).

EDIT: Should perhaps mention that including the attribute sep=',' doesn't solve the issue)

My code looks like this

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None, quotechar='"')

print(df.head)
print(len(df.columns))
print(len(df.index))
```

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Here is a subset of the data as text

```
10-01-2021,813,116927,"2,01",-,-,-
11-01-2021,657,117584,"2,02",-,-,-
12-01-2021,462,118046,"2,03",-,-,-
13-01-2021,12728,130774,"2,24",-,-,-
14-01-2021,17895,148669,"2,55",-,-,-
15-01-2021,15206,163875,"2,81",5,5,"0,0001"
16-01-2021,4612,168487,"2,89",7,12,"0,0002"
17-01-2021,2536,171023,"2,93",717,729,"0,01"
18-01-2021,3883,174906,"3,00",2147,2876,"0,05"
```

Here is the output of the head-function

```
                                                    0
0                   27-12-2020,6492,6492,"0,11",-,-,-
1                   28-12-2020,1987,8479,"0,15",-,-,-
2                  29-12-2020,8961,17440,"0,30",-,-,-
3                 30-12-2020,11477,28917,"0,50",-,-,-
4                  31-12-2020,6197,35114,"0,60",-,-,-
5                  01-01-2021,2344,37458,"0,64",-,-,-
6                  02-01-2021,8895,46353,"0,80",-,-,-
7                  03-01-2021,6024,52377,"0,90",-,-,-
8                  04-01-2021,2403,54780,"0,94",-,-,-
```

Comment: could you provide the data as text instead of an image. That way people can try to reproduce your results.

Comment: Did you try `sep=','` ?

Comment: @Rubens_Zimbres: Yes, forgot to mention that I have tried that. Doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @Jonas: yes, good idea, but I don't have anywhere to upload my .csv file. :(

Comment: Just copypaste some of its lines in the question, select them and press ctrl+k

Comment: you can just copy paste a few field from your csv in your post.

Comment: Please post the output of the head() command

Comment: @gtome I'll include the output of the head function in the original post in 2 secs

Comment: Strange. it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your data I got the expected result. (even without `quotechar='"'`)

Could you maybe show us your output?

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None)

print(df)
>             0      1       2     3     4     5       6
> 0  10-01-2021    813  116927  2,01     -     -       -
> 1  11-01-2021    657  117584  2,02     -     -       -
> 2  12-01-2021    462  118046  2,03     -     -       -
> 3  13-01-2021  12728  130774  2,24     -     -       -
> 4  14-01-2021  17895  148669  2,55     -     -       -
> 5  15-01-2021  15206  163875  2,81     5     5  0,0001
> 6  16-01-2021   4612  168487  2,89     7    12  0,0002
> 7  17-01-2021   2536  171023  2,93   717   729    0,01
> 8  18-01-2021   3883  174906  3,00  2147  2876    0,05
```

Comment: That's how I want it to look like! But when I do it, I get the output as shown by the end of my post (just edited it)

Comment: can you try if you have the same results if you repeat my code on only the lines you shared? If it works, there is something wrong with your file. If it still doesn't there is something with your environment

Comment: It works with only the subset. And it works if I copy the data and save it as a new csv file. Weird. Thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate it!

Comment: Weird. But good that your problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the seperator and delimiter, like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None, sep = ',', delimiter=',' , quotechar='"')
```

Comment: `sep = ','` is default.

Comment: I have tried that but it didn't solve the issue. :-(

Comment: @gtomer didn't help to include the delimiter either :(

Comment: Hard to say without the CSV. can you post a link to the CSV?

Comment: Seems like my CSV file was corrupt for some reason. Solved the problem to copy the data into a new csv file.